# Mjpeg text based subtitle extraction/replay

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, mjpeg

I have an MJPEG based avi file that I cannot replay satisfactorily.

The video I can correctly replay in FFPlay but i cannot replay or demux the text based subtitle stream.

The file contains time/date stamps in the subtitles embedded as ascii text which i can see between the video packets (when viewed in a hex reader).

FFmpeg cannot identify the subtitle codec b7t can see that there is a subtitle stream.

Ive tried a number of filter combinations using GraphStudioNext. I found a couple of working solutions (when previewed in GraphStudio when served to avisynth the subtitles had disappeared again. I checked the filtergraph and the pin out from the avi splitter had misteriously disconnected. I cannot find a way out of this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how i might demux the subtitle stream(short of writing a converter to extract the text to srt based on the packet timing)?

This is my first post so apologies if i havent observed etiquette.

Comment: Please provide a sample file if possible.

Comment: Sorry I cannot, though i will if i am able to get hold of the source software to produce a test file.